# Angular momentum conservation while internal frictional torque is present

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, friction, conservation-laws

So this appears in a problem which looks simple enough in its context; It's something like this:

> *Two discs, **A** and **B**, are mounted coaxially on a vertical axle. The discs have moments of inertia $I$ and $2I$ respectively about the common axis. Disc A is imparted an initial angular velocity $2\omega$ using the entire potential energy of a spring compressed by a distance $x_1$. Disc B is imparted an angular velocity $\omega$ by the same spring compressed by a distance $x_2$. Both the discs rotate in the clockwise direction.*
>
> *When disc B was brought in contact with A, they acquire a common angular velocity in time $t$. The average frictional torque by the other during this period is: **?***

The answer ($2I\omega/3t$) was obtained by applying angular momentum conservation and is exactly what confused me. **How can we apply angular momentum conservation when friction is present?**

Answer (score 6):

The angular momentum of each disk individually is not conserved, however the total angular momentum of both disks **is** conserved because there are no *external* torques acting.

Start by calculating the total angular momentum of both disks (I'm going to replace "w" by "v" since "w" is confusingly close to "$\omega$"):

$$\begin{align}
L_{total} &= I_a \omega_a + I_b \omega_b \\
          &= I.2v + 2I.v \\
          &= 4Iv
\end{align}$$

Now we bring the disks into contact and they settle down to a constant speed $\omega_{final}$. The total angular momentum is now:

$$\begin{align}
L_{total} &= I_a \omega_{final} + I_b \omega_{final} \\
          &= 3I\omega_{final}
\end{align}$$

Because angular momentum is conserved we just equate our two expressions fo $L_{total}$:

$$ 4Iv = 3I\omega_{final} $$

so:

$$ \omega_{final} = \frac{4}{3}v $$

Now, torque $\times$ time is the angular impulse, and we know that the impulse is equal to the change of momentum. So if we calculate the change in momentum of disk A this is equal to the torque times the time i.e. $Tt$, and we know the initial angular momentum of disk A is $2Iv$ so:

$$\begin{align}
Tt &= I_a 2v - I_a \omega_{final} \\
   &= 2Iv - \frac{4}{3}Iv \\
   &= \frac{2}{3}Iv
\end{align}$$

And dividing both sides by $t$ gives the answer:

$$ T = \frac{2}{3} \frac{Iv}{t} $$

Answer (score 4):

> How can we apply angular momentum conservation when friction is present?

Why not? If we have a closed system, momentum and angular momentum are conserved. In this case, the full system is disk A and disk B, and there are no external forces, so the system is closed. There **are** internal forces, namely in this case, friction, but that doesn't matter.

You might be mixing this up with conservation of **mechanical** energy, which is not conserved if there is friction. (but total energy still is - if you include heat loss etc.)

(Note that this implies that the exact form of the frictional force is irrelevant.)